# Fourier transform of shifted impulse and function

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I'm currently struggling with this:

> *Calculate the fourier transform of* 
>    $t^2·δ(t-a)$

I've tried applying the derivative property of the fourier transform to simplify things but to no avail. Would there be a way of applying the sifting property to make things easier? I also tried an inverse tranform of the convultion of the two functions but things became way to messy. I think there has to be a simpler solution that I'm missing.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: I'm new to the site and not really sure about how everything works. I've tried to explain what I have done myself in words as it is quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier than you think:
$$\mathcal F\{ t^2 \delta(t-a) \} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t^2 \delta(t-a) e^{-i \omega t} \, dt = \left. t^2 e^{-i \omega t} \right|_{t=a} = a^2 e^{-i \omega a}$$
where it has been used that 
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \, \delta(t-a) \, dt = f(a).$

Comment: Thanks so much md2perpe! Didn't think of putting the $e^(-iwa)$ inside the $f(t)$ of the sifting property.